# Add Div as a parameter to a function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET C# code.

I have some div elements with I set `runat="Server"` and they have ID's

I need to know how to pass these as parameters to a function.

So

> `public  void A(type Div1) { }`

In above what type Div 1 is?

Comment: It should be `HtmlGenericControl`. You need to import `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div's are very generic in fact they are `HtmlGenericControl("div")`.  You can simply make them Panels and pass them in asp.net as `Panel`.

Try it out, create an `<asp:Panel id="myPanel" runat="server" />` and run your html, look at its source.  The panel translates to a div in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET should create page variables of type `HtmlGenericControl` for each ID that you declare.  For example, if your ID was `Div1` then you could do the following:

```
string myText = Div1.InnerText;
```